# How can I find the UUID for network cards?

Tags: networking, fedora, network-adapter, uuid

It's easy to see them in use on, for example, a modern Fedora Core Server - like on version 30 — in the network configuration scripts found in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` directory.

Okay, I want to change things around by hand; how do I find these on my own without having to do a fresh install?

What I really want to do is have my network script correctly identify the NIC I want to configure. Please see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551459/following-clone-of-fedora-core-30-server-to-new-hardware-one-nic-is-missing-b) for background.

Comment: Do you want to *find* these things on your own or do you want to *change*/*create* them on your own? Look at [this article on how to generate UUID’s manually](https://www.itechlounge.net/2014/03/linux-how-to-generate-uuid-for-network-interface-on-rhelcentos/) to see if that helps.

Comment: @JakeGould Good question; I didn't know that I COULD create one myself! They've long been a minor mystery I haven't had time to figure out, so I appreciate the pointer. ...So, does that mean Fedora is just creating them on the fly and assigning them somehow? Hmmm... Will go read from your link.

Comment: @JakeGould Two quick points: 1) I just updated the question, and 2) I bet you could fashion your comment into a correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

Since now some three years hence I needed this same information again, and as my own question here came up as the TOP web search item, and as I just learned something Jake Gould didn't share, I figure this is worthy of providing:

Again, on Fedora (in this instance FC 38), this gets you the data:

```
# nmcli c
```

It also works on the several older Fedora versions I have at hand, including 35.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Ah, but... this UUID doesn't identify the NIC at all, it identifies only the config script itself. It's randomly generated whenever NM creates a config. (The MAC and/or interface name is how NM binds configs to NICs.)

Comment: @user1686 It's true it goes to the apparent name, however, I WISH it was true that "The MAC and/or interface name is how NM binds configs to NICs." NOT on Fedora 38 it doesn't! And that's exactly WHY I had to figure this out once more - because the ... ahem -SCREWBALL!- Network Manager software decided to ignore the MAC and ... I actually got a DHCP derived address I never asked for! ... NM is all screwed up! (STILL!) The quick fix was using the MAC with DHCP and THEN to identify the UUCP in the config file. ...WTH is the point of UUID if it's NOT identifying the NIC accurately?!